# Running JS functions on Selenium RC .Net

Tags: c#, javascript, unit-testing, nunit, selenium-rc

I have a index.html file which includes scripts.js

in scripts.js:

function Add(arg1, arg2)

{

```
if(typeof(arg1) == 'string') arg1 = parseInt(arg1);

if(typeof(arg2) == 'string') arg2 = parseInt(arg2);

return arg1 + arg2;
```

}

in my C# code:

[Test]

public void Tescik()

{

```
   Assert.AreEqual(sel.GetEval(@"this.browserbot.getUserWindow().Add(2,3);"), 5, "Adding...");
```

}

when run in NUnit it fails with:

ERROR: Threw an exception: this.browserbot.getUserWindow().Add is not a function

any suggestions what's wrong? I have both sel.start() and stop()

Answer (score 0):

It's `this.browserbot.getCurrentWindow()...`, not `...getUserWindow...`.